# Do I need to clearTimeout in react function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using 'setTimout()' in a function and I am not calling that function in 'useEffect()' do I still need to find a way to clear timeout?

```
const RandomComponent = () =>{

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const aFunction = () => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setClicked(true);
    },1000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={aFunction}>Click me!</button>
    </div>  
  )

}
```

Something like above code, in this situation do I need to clear timeout? thanks

*Updated question:

```
const RandomComponent = () =>{

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const aFunction = (evt) => {
    return setTimeout(()=>{
      setClicked(true);
    },30000);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    return ()=>{
      // how to clear setTimeout in 'aFunction' when I unmount this component?
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={aFunction}>Click me!</button>
    </div>  
  )

}
```

Comment: We need to clear an interval if we called `setInterval`. But we don't need to do it in the case of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to clear the timeout if you want the timer not to fire if it hasn't already fired. If it's already fired, or you don't care if it fires in the future, you don't need to cancel it.

Since you're starting the timer on a button click, if the timer callback uses state information when it runs (the one in the question doesn't), the state information it closes over may be stale, but it can get fresh state information via the setter function if it needs it. But if the timer might fire after the component is unmounted, using the setter like that would cause an error about updating state on an unmounted component. It's hard to give you a *general* solution to that, as a general solution is usually not as good as a solution that's specific to what you're doing in the timer callback.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> if when the time comes and I need to clean up/clear my setTimeout in a function when I unmount the component, how do I do it? cause if I am calling setTimeout in useEffect I can just put the setTimeout in a variable and clearTimeout(theSetTimoutVariable) inside of return function in useeffect but how do I do it in a function that is going to get called by onClick button with an event argument?

The fact is I don't know the "right" React way to do that, and I'd like to.

I know of *a* way to do it, which is to use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array and non-state instance data, like this:

```
// A utility function that cancels a timer callback if necessary and
// returns a 0 you can assign to the timer handler variable
function cancelTimer(handle) {
    if (handle) {
        clearTimer(handle);
    }
    return 0;
}

const Example = () => {
    // Non-state instance data
    const {current: instance} = useRef({});

    // Cleanup on dismount
    useEffect(() => {
        // Mounting
        // ...

        return () => {
            // Dismounting

            // If we have an outstanding timer, cancel it
            instance.timer = cancelTimer(instance.timer);
        };
    }, []); // <=== Empty array means the callback is only called on mount,
            //      and the one it returns is only called on dismount

    const onButtonClick = () => {
        instance.timer = cancelTimer(instance.timer);
        instance.timer setTimeout(() => {
            // ...
        }, 1000);
    };

    return (/*...*/);
};
```

Comment: Although if the component gets unmounted, it will complain about trying to update state on an unmounted component.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What would you suggest if the function is setInterval instead of setTimeout. How would Javascript Garbage collection work with this

Comment: what about clean up situation, I forgot where I saw it but few weeks ago I saw an article saying something about clean up setTimeout or setInterval if you use them, do I need to clean up in this situation and I don't fully understand the clean up thing, when do I need to use clean up?(return in useEffect) thanks

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - Garbage collection is really a side issue here, and mostly only relevant to `setInterval`.

Comment: @MrBear77 - I'm sorry, I can't really understand that comment. *"... few weeks ago I saw an article saying something about clean up setTimeout or setInterval if you use them..."* `setInterval`, yes; `setTimeout`, no, not unless it hasn't fired and you don't want it to, as I said above. *"do I need to clean up in this situation"* As I said above, it depends on what you're doing. *"and I don't fully understand the clean up thing, when do I need to use clean up"* Again, it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: hi, sorry for that comment, yeah after I re-read your answer carefully I kind get it now, just another quick question if when the time comes and I need to clean up/clear my setTimeout in a function when I unmount the component, how do I do it? cause if I am calling setTimeout in useEffect I can just put the setTimeout in a variable and clearTimeout(theSetTimoutVariable) inside of return function in useeffect but how do I do it in a function that is going to get called by onClick button with an event argument? 
(I updated my question, first post)

Comment: @MrBear77 - No worries! I've added to the answer with *a* way I know to do it. I've never been really sure it was the best way, though. It does work. :-)